# Density of sets in the product space $X= \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Let $X= \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ and suppose that $X$ has the product topology. Let $A$ be the set of functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ for which $f(x) \in \Bbb Q$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and $f(x)=0$ for all but finitely many $x$. Let $B$ be the set of $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ for which $f(x)=0$ when $x \in \Bbb Q$. Is $A$ or $B$ dense in $X$?

Since for $f_n \in A$ we have that $f_n \to 0$ as there is only finitely many $x$ for which $f(x)\ne 0$ and the zero function is in $X$. I think that $A$ is dense in $X$.

For $B$ since in any sequence $g_n \in B$ the elements $g_i(x)$ only evaluate to $0$ countably many times. I don't think this sequence converges to any $g \in A$.

Is my hunch correct here or am I making some kind of obvious mistake?

Comment: Remember that with arbitrary topological spaces, arguments involving sequences often don't work like they do with metric spaces, and instead nets or filters are used.

Comment: But aren't I working with just the arbitary product of metric spaces here?

Comment: @Ylvas The product topology is for a product of *topological* spaces. Of course, $\mathbb{R}$ is a metrisable (it has a metric), but I don't see how a metric would carry through to an uncountable product in this case. For example, functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be unbounded and behave it all sorts of weird ways.

Comment: A subset can be closed under sequential limits but still dense in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. The product space is not a sequential space so arguments with sequences are not to be trusted.

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor An uncountable product of non-trivial spaces is never metrisable indeed.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is dense as is easy to see (it intersects every basic open set that is non-empty). $B$ is not as it's  closed and not the whole space.

That $B$ is closed follows from $B = \bigcap_{q \in \Bbb Q} \pi_q^{-1}[\{0\}]$

Comment: The argument with sequences doesn't work here?

Comment: @Ylvas no the product space is not sequential.

Comment: But it's quite hard to work with open sets in the product topology. I know that $A$ is dense if $A \cap U \ne \emptyset$ for all $U \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, but the open sets $U$ are either some infinite products or finite intersections of the projection preimages. In either of these I don't know how they must intersect $A$.

Comment: @Ylvas the basic open sets are finite intersections of inverse images of open sets under projections. Quite simple.

Comment: I've tried to find example problems with these infinite product spaces, but lots of books are not very thorough with the chapters on product topology. Any suggestions on some books you might now?

Comment: @Ylvas engelking general topology is quite thorough on product spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried to workout why $A$ would be dense without using sequences, but I don't see how to do this. I am to show that $$\bigcap_{i \in F} \pi_{i}^{-1}(O_i) \cap A$$ is non-empty. Each $\pi_{i}^{-1}(O_i)$ is of form $$\{f \in X : \pi_{i}(f) \in O_i\} = \{f \in X : f(i) \in O_i\}$$ and $O_i$ open set in $\Bbb R$. I don't think it follows immediately that these two sets intersects.

Comment: @Ylvas define the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by setting $f(i)$ for $i \in F$ to some $q_i \in \Bbb Q\cap O_i$ and equal to $0$ for all other values. By definition it is in this intersection. We only need that that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in the reals so intersects all non-empty  open sets